# a way to convert json files into jsonnet files?

Tags: json, devops, grafana, jsonnet

is there a way to convert json files into jsonnet files?
I am working on grafana dashboards as code and need to convert a json file into jsonnet. Or is there a good guide on how to create panels in Grfana except the official Jsonnet website? I would be glad if I recieved any help from you!

Answer (score 1):

JSON files are "technically" jsonnet files already, you can prettify them to look like jsonnet with:

```bash
jsonnetfmt file.json > file.jsonnet
```

Of course, the above is just syntax-sugar'izing the original JSON file.

If you want to build Grafana dashboards in a programmatic way, [grafonnet-lib](https://grafana.github.io/grafonnet-lib/getting-started/) would be the way to go

---

Comment: Actually that did not do anything to my json file. The script is all the same and long as before, but just as jsonnet format.